# App is installed but not stating in my android device

Tags: android

app installed successfully but not starting on emulator here i am using services ,may be i do wrong in starting the service here i am placing the manifest and console details any one help to start my app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        package="fi.harism.wallpaper.flowers"
        android:versionCode="10"
        android:versionName="3.2" >

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_application"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <service
                android:name=".FlowerService"
                android:description="@string/description"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
                </intent-filter>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                    android:resource="@xml/flowers" />
            </service>

            <activity
                android:name=".prefs.FlowerPreferenceActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="@string/preferences_name" />
        </application>

    </manifest>

    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] Android Launch!
    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] adb is running normally.
    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] No Launcher activity found!
    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] Performing sync
    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AVD_4.0'
    [2012-12-14 14:33:30 - flowers] Uploading flowers.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
    [2012-12-14 14:33:31 - flowers] Installing flowers.apk...
    [2012-12-14 14:33:37 - flowers] Success!
    [2012-12-14 14:33:37 - flowers] \flowers\bin\flowers.apk installed on device
    [2012-12-14 14:33:37 - flowers] Done!
```

Comment: i imported 3 android live wallpaper projects having same problem,but other projects working fine.

Comment: what do you actually expect it to do ?

Comment: i trying to do live wallpaper example.

Answer (score 1):

inside the Intent filter apply this code.

```
 <activity
    android:name=".prefs.FlowerPreferenceActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/preferences_name"> 
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
 </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: check the update answer, also wallpaper is not an activity, you need to long press on home screen and start the installed wallpaper

Comment: showing error -->The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element